# Printing a list of files folders modified today

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Is there any way to print the list of files, folders in a directory modified today on windows 7? Kindly help

Comment: closest easy thing to do is `dir /o-d` which lists most recently modified first, and then you can see by eye which was today.

Comment: How do I print those

Comment: do you mean print on a printer, or display on the screen?  You can do `dir /o-d >a.a`   or  `dir /o-d/b >a.a`  and then open the a.a file in notepad  and  click file..print .   or open it in ms word and do ctrl-p in ms word to print.